# ios BTLE didDiscoverPeripheral change discovery time interval

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

im using BTLE for reacting to some BTLE devices,
I just need to know when the BTLE device is in certain range,
I dont need to pair, just know the RSSI value,

the problem i have is that the rate of

> didDiscoverPeripheral

is about 10 seconds intervals

Can I change this interval time to make it shorter?

Thanks!

Comment: I am not clear with your question , but my understanding is like you want your didDiscoverPeripheral method to be called faster ?

Comment: correct! can I speed this up? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in CoreBluetooth didDiscoverPeripheral method called when device finds new peripheral . Also you can give options in dictionary like :

```
NSDictionary * options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@YES, CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey, nil];
```

Making that CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey to yes makes the didDiscoverPeripheral to called whenever the RSSI of the peripheral changed from previous . This is quite fast like didDiscoverPeripheral get called in almost millisecond . First check your dictionary flag whether it is set to YES or not . otherwise there may be  something wrong with your peripheral . Try to test it with different peripheral .

Answer (score 1):

I made the experience to implement two methods for scanning for Peripheral. I usually use the option CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey:FALSE for normal scans. I always implement a method called targetScan to scan for peripheral an a specific time pattern. So you can implement a dispatch timer with a interval of 10 seconds. Every time this timer is dispatched and fire call a method with "ScanForPeripheral" with option CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey:TRUE after 2 seconds you can quitThis specific scan and invoke the "normal scanning mode" with CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey:FALSE

Hope this helps !